# cascade dropdown list does not work after reopening the form

Tags: jquery

I have two kendo drop down lists, second one binds based on the first one, when I open the form it works perfectly, but when I reopen the form, whatever I choose from the first list, the second dropdown list shows the last data from the previous form, the following is my first drop down list:

```
function deviceTypesList(container, options)
{
    $('<input  name="DeviceType" id="DeviceType" data-type="string" \">')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: mydata_deviceType,                                   
            dataTextField: "Text",
            dataValueField: "Text",
            valuePrimitive: true,
            //change: onChange,
            select: function (e) {

                var item = this.dataItem(e.item);
                var s = item.Text;

                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("modelProducer","AdminTool")",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "turbineType": s, }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        modelProducerResult = data;
                        var ddl = $("#ModelProducer").data("kendoDropDownList");
                        // ddl.dataSource.data({}); // clears dataSource
                        //ddl.dataSource.data({});
                        ddl.text(""); // clears visible text
                        ddl.value("");
                        // $("#ModelProducer").empty();
                        $("#ModelProducer")
                            .data("kendoDropDownList")
                            .dataSource.data(modelProducerResult);

                        debugger;
                    }
                });
            }
            //dataValueField: "ProductName",
        });
}
```

Here is the second one which binds based on the first one:

```
function modelProducer(container, options)
{
    var t = modelProducerResult;

    $('<input  name="ModelProducer" id="ModelProducer" data-type="string" style="width: 100%"\">')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: modelProducerResult,
        dataTextField: "model",
        dataValueField: "model",
        valuePrimitive: true,
    });

    debugger;
}
```

Comment: You URL definition, `url: "@Url.Action("modelProducer","AdminTool")",` seems to be wrong here. I would imagine that you have different types of quotes in your original?

Comment: @AlexisWilke whats wrong with that?

Comment: The quotes are all the same. Unless you have a first pass that ignores the external quotes... I don't know of kendo or whatever other tool you might use. Otherwise, something like this would probably work better: `url: "@Url.Action('modelProducer','AdminTool')"`

Comment: @AlexisWilke I tried what you said but in kendo what I did is correct

Comment: Have you tried to see whether `modelProducer()` gets called the second time? It could be that Kendo sees those as already defined and just reuse whatever was created earlier. Adding a `console.log("got here")` at the beginning of the function would do.

Comment: @AlexisWilke the second time I checked the value of modelProducer,its the right value(the one I expect)but the strange thing is its drop downlist still shows the previous call value!!!imagine the datasource of dropdownlist is something and what dropdownlist is showing is something else! how come?

Comment: The one thing I could think of is that it creates a new item but still uses the old one. I'm not too sure how they manage the elements but that would be my guess...